# Spring Data JPA - How to programmatically set JpaRepository base packages

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

When defining an EntityManager in a Spring Java Config class, I can add the base packages to scan for Entity classes by calling a method on the corresponding builder:

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
  // Some other configuration here
  builder.packages("org.foo.bar", "org.foo.baz");
  return builder.build();
}
```

I need something similar for the places where Spring looks for Repository Interfaces. The usual way is using the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.foo.barbaz"})
```

But I would like to have a dynamical way for defining these packages similar to the way above for the Entity locations. Something like this:

```
public SomeJpaRepositoryFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBuilder builder) {
  // Some other configuration here
  builder.packages("org.foo.barbaz");
  return builder.build();
}
```

Is there a way to do this with the current Spring Data JPA release is it simply not meant to be done this way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this programatically?

Comment: To allow other application modules to add their repository base packages to a List or Set before passing its contents to Spring. The same already works for entities (as shown above) and would be very handy to have for repositories as well (to prevent the "core app" from having knowledge about the module's package structure)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to pass a configuration class to the "core app" and include that in the configuration. This in turn could have all the `EnableX` annotations it wants.

Comment: I'm also interested in an answer.

Comment: The way how the spring scans repositories is complex, that's a good reason to encapsulate it using this annotation and the easy class is not public. So, you should delegate to clients of your library to anotate with @EnableJpaRepositories.

Comment: @NorbertoRitzmann Is it possible to have multiple classes annotated with `@EnableJpaRepositories`? At least in my case, that would probably solve my current issue. I'll give it a try on Monday. If it really works, feel free to create an answer in order to receive the bounty :-)

Comment: I dont think it is possible, once you have defined you cannot add more repositories.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `@AutoConfigurationPackage` annotation to add your child module's package to scan-packages.

1. **Remove** all `@EnableJpaRepositories` from your **child module**
2. Add `@AutoConfigurationPackage` class to the **top directory of your child module** (similar to `@SpringBootApplication`, you must put this class to the top-most directory to scan all subpackages):

   ```
   @AutoConfigurationPackage
   public class ChildConfiguration {
   }
   ```
3. Create `spring.factories` file under **`/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`** of **your child module** and add the configuration class:

   `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.child.package.ChildConfiguration`

Now you can `@Autowired` your repository from your core project. (Tested and worked)

Comment: I don't have Spring Boot, just plain Spring with Web MVC. So There is no `@AutoConfigurationPackage` for me.

Comment: Sorry, if you're using MVC then there's no conflict with `@SpringBoo`t, just straight add `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your child module

Comment: I thought it would only scan for this annotation once. If every JAR module may have its own `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, then my problem is indeed solved.I'll try it Monday and then let you know about the result :-)

Comment: Your comment solved my problem, so I happily assign the bounty to your answer. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: It might be a silly question, but aren't you supposed to declared the `entityManagerFactoryRef`and the `transactionManagerRef` in your `@EnableJpaRepositories` ? How are you gonna do that with `AutoConfigurationPackage` ?

Answer (score 6):

## Without Spring Boot (plain Spring MVC setup)

`@EnableJpaRepositories` can be used on more than one `@Configuration` class. That said, every module can declare its own repositories by having an own configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package1")
public class ConfigClass1 { /* ... */ }

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "package2")
public class ConfigClass2 { /* ... */ }
```

Spring Data JPA then counts in all of them (`package1` and `package2`).

Although this is still not a programmatical way, it solves my problem.

Comment: Side note: Both classes are located in different JAR modules.

Comment: what is they use the same data source ?

Answer (score 3):

This problem also puzzled me for almost a week.I debug the "spring application context refresh" code and `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoriesRegistrar` line by line and then I solve the problem.

I customize my `EnableJpaRepository` annotation and `JpaRepositoriesRegistrar`,then I can do anything in `AbdJpaRepositoriesRegistrar`("abd" is my customized classes's prefix).

AbdEnableJpaRepositories.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.DefaultRepositoryBaseClass;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy.Key;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * basePackages
 * 复制EnableJpaRepositories，Import自定义的AbdJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.
 * Copy from EnableJpaRepositories，Import customized AbdJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.
 *
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Thomas Darimont
 * @author ghj
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Import(AbdJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.class)
public @interface AbdEnableJpaRepositories {

    /**
     * Alias for the {@link #basePackages()} attribute. Allows for more concise annotation declarations e.g.:
     * {@code @EnableJpaRepositories("org.my.pkg")} instead of {@code @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="org.my.pkg")}.
     */
    String value() default "";

    /**
     * Base packages to scan for annotated components. {@link #value()} is an alias for (and mutually exclusive with) this
     * attribute. Use {@link #basePackageClasses()} for a type-safe alternative to String-based package names.
     */
    String basePackages() default "";

    /**
     * Type-safe alternative to {@link #basePackages()} for specifying the packages to scan for annotated components. The
     * package of each class specified will be scanned. Consider creating a special no-op marker class or interface in
     * each package that serves no purpose other than being referenced by this attribute.
     */
    Class<?>[] basePackageClasses() default {};

    /**
     * Specifies which types are eligible for component scanning. Further narrows the set of candidate components from
     * everything in {@link #basePackages()} to everything in the base packages that matches the given filter or filters.
     */
    Filter[] includeFilters() default {};

    /**
     * Specifies which types are not eligible for component scanning.
     */
    Filter[] excludeFilters() default {};

    /**
     * Returns the postfix to be used when looking up custom repository implementations. Defaults to {@literal Impl}. So
     * for a repository named {@code PersonRepository} the corresponding implementation class will be looked up scanning
     * for {@code PersonRepositoryImpl}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    String repositoryImplementationPostfix() default "Impl";

    /**
     * Configures the location of where to find the Spring Data named queries properties file. Will default to
     * {@code META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    String namedQueriesLocation() default "";

    /**
     * Returns the key of the {@link QueryLookupStrategy} to be used for lookup queries for query methods. Defaults to
     * {@link Key#CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    Key queryLookupStrategy() default Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND;

    /**
     * Returns the {@link FactoryBean} class to be used for each repository instance. Defaults to
     * {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    Class<?> repositoryFactoryBeanClass() default JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class;

    /**
     * Configure the repository base class to be used to create repository proxies for this particular configuration.
     *
     * @return
     * @since 1.9
     */
    Class<?> repositoryBaseClass() default DefaultRepositoryBaseClass.class;

    // JPA specific configuration

    /**
     * Configures the name of the {@link EntityManagerFactory} bean definition to be used to create repositories
     * discovered through this annotation. Defaults to {@code entityManagerFactory}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    String entityManagerFactoryRef() default "entityManagerFactory";

    /**
     * Configures the name of the {@link PlatformTransactionManager} bean definition to be used to create repositories
     * discovered through this annotation. Defaults to {@code transactionManager}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    String transactionManagerRef() default "transactionManager";

    /**
     * Configures whether nested repository-interfaces (e.g. defined as inner classes) should be discovered by the
     * repositories infrastructure.
     */
    boolean considerNestedRepositories() default false;

    /**
     * Configures whether to enable default transactions for Spring Data JPA repositories. Defaults to {@literal true}. If
     * disabled, repositories must be used behind a facade that's configuring transactions (e.g. using Spring's annotation
     * driven transaction facilities) or repository methods have to be used to demarcate transactions.
     *
     * @return whether to enable default transactions, defaults to {@literal true}.
     */
    boolean enableDefaultTransactions() default true;
}
```

AbdJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtension;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

class AbdJpaRepositoriesRegistrar extends AbdRepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport#getAnnotation()
     */
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotation() {
        return AbdEnableJpaRepositories.class;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport#getExtension()
     */
    @Override
    protected RepositoryConfigurationExtension getExtension() {
        return new JpaRepositoryConfigExtension();
    }
}
```

AbdRepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtension;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationUtils;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

/**
 *
 * @author ghj
 */
abstract class AbdRepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport extends RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar,
    ResourceLoaderAware, EnvironmentAware {

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {

        Assert.notNull(resourceLoader, "ResourceLoader must not be null!");
        Assert.notNull(annotationMetadata, "AnnotationMetadata must not be null!");
        Assert.notNull(registry, "BeanDefinitionRegistry must not be null!");

        // Guard against calls for sub-classes
        if (annotationMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(getAnnotation().getName()) == null) {
            return;
        }

        // 使用自定义的AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource
        AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource configurationSource = new AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(
            annotationMetadata, getAnnotation(), resourceLoader, environment);

        RepositoryConfigurationExtension extension = getExtension();
        RepositoryConfigurationUtils.exposeRegistration(extension, registry, configurationSource);

        RepositoryConfigurationDelegate delegate = new RepositoryConfigurationDelegate(configurationSource, resourceLoader,
            environment);

        delegate.registerRepositoriesIn(registry, extension);
    }
}
```

AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.java. You can override `getBasePackages` then you can return any packages you want.

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
/**
 *
 * @author ghj
 */
class AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource extends AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource {
    private static final String BASE_PACKAGES = "basePackages";
    private static final String BASE_PACKAGE_CLASSES = "basePackageClasses";

    private final AnnotationMetadata configMetadata;
    private final AnnotationAttributes attributes;
    private final Environment environment;

    AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(AnnotationMetadata metadata, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation, ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Environment environment) {
        super(metadata, annotation, resourceLoader, environment);

        this.attributes = new AnnotationAttributes(metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(annotation.getName()));
        this.configMetadata = metadata;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<String> getBasePackages() {

        String value = attributes.getStringArray("value")[0];
        String basePackages = attributes.getStringArray(BASE_PACKAGES)[0];
        Class<?>[] basePackageClasses = attributes.getClassArray(BASE_PACKAGE_CLASSES);

        // Default configuration - return package of annotated class
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(value) && StringUtils.isEmpty(basePackages) && basePackageClasses.length == 0) {
            String className = configMetadata.getClassName();
            return Collections.singleton(ClassUtils.getPackageName(className));
        }

        String[] packagesFromValue = parsePackagesSpel(value);
        String[] packagesFromBasePackages = parsePackagesSpel(basePackages);

        Set<String> packages = new HashSet<>();
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(packagesFromValue));
        packages.addAll(Arrays.asList(packagesFromBasePackages));

        for (Class<?> typeName : basePackageClasses) {
            packages.add(ClassUtils.getPackageName(typeName));
        }

        return packages;
    }

    private String[] parsePackagesSpel(String raw) {
        if (!raw.trim().startsWith("$")) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(raw)) {
                return new String[]{};
            }
            return raw.split(",");
        } else {
            raw = raw.trim();
            String packages = this.environment.getProperty(raw.substring("${".length(), raw.length() - "}".length()));
            return packages.split(",");
        }
    }
}
```

How to use?Here is configuration file.
PrimaryJpaConfiguration.java

```
import com.shinow.abd.springjpa2.annotation.AbdEnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@AbdEnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "${spring.jpa.base-packages}",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class PrimaryJpaConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "entityManager")
    @Primary
    public EntityManager entityManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = JpaProperties.get("", env);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("spring.jpa.base-packages").split(","));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }
}
```

You can add `spring.jpa.base-packages` config to your application.properties.
For example:`spring.jpa.base-packages=com.foo.a,com.bar.b`,and the repositories and entities under those packages "com.foo.a" and "com.bar.b" will be added to the spring Ioc container.

Comment: I use `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.8.RELEASE")` and `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.8.RELEASE")`.I guess newer version may be a little different in code and I believe the train of thoughts should be same.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by 高慧觉 [Spring Data JPA - How to programmatically set JpaRepository base packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages/51629110#51629110) worked for me, but I've come up with a simpler and more reliable `AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource` implementation: just allow Spring Data to collect the packages in its way, and then post-process them and expand property placeholders to package names.

```
class AbdAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource extends AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource {

    private final Environment environment;

    ExpressionsSupportingAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(AnnotationMetadata metadata, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation,
            ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Environment environment, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        super(metadata, annotation, resourceLoader, environment, registry);

        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public Streamable<String> getBasePackages() {
        Streamable<String> rawPackages = super.getBasePackages();
        return Streamable.of(() -> rawPackages.stream()
                .flatMap(raw -> parsePackagesSpel(raw).stream())
        );
    }

    private List<String> parsePackagesSpel(@Nullable String rawPackage) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(rawPackage, "Package specification cannot be null");

        if (!rawPackage.trim().startsWith("$")) {
            return Collections.singletonList(rawPackage);
        }

        rawPackage = rawPackage.trim();
        String propertyName = rawPackage.substring("${".length(), rawPackage.length() - "}".length());
        String packages = this.environment.getProperty(propertyName);

        if (!StringUtils.hasText(packages)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    String.format("Could not resolve the following packages definition: %s", rawPackage));
        }

        return Arrays.stream(packages.split(","))
                .map(String::trim)
                .filter(StringUtils::hasText)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a way to invoke `@EnableJpaRepositories` purely programmatically. For the purpose I've created a class which simulates the Annotation data passed to a config class annotated with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. I called my class `EnableJpaRepositoriesData`. It is confirmed working with Spring 5.1.5, SpringBoot 2.1.3. I guess it must be compatible with earlier and later versions alike, with none or very little changes at most.

Below follows the class code, and a sample usage code for it.

> **EnableJpaRepositoriesData.java:**

```
package org.patladj.jpa.config.multijpa;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;
import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;


public class EnableJpaRepositoriesData extends AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor implements AnnotationMetadata {

    private Map<String, ?> data;

    private void initIt() throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {

        //################## protected final Set<String> annotationSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(4);
        annotationSet.add(Configuration.class.getCanonicalName());
        annotationSet.add(EnableTransactionManagement.class.getCanonicalName());
        annotationSet.add(EnableJpaRepositories.class.getCanonicalName());

        //################## protected final Map<String, Set<String>> metaAnnotationMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(4);
        metaAnnotationMap.put(Configuration.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                        Component.class.getCanonicalName(),
                        Indexed.class.getCanonicalName()
                )));
        metaAnnotationMap.put(EnableTransactionManagement.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                        Import.class.getCanonicalName()
                )));
        metaAnnotationMap.put(EnableJpaRepositories.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                        Import.class.getCanonicalName()
                )));

        //################## protected final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, AnnotationAttributes> attributesMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(4);
        attributesMap.put(Configuration.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedList<AnnotationAttributes>() {{
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("value", defaultFor(Configuration.class, "value"));
                    }}));
                }});

        attributesMap.put(Component.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedList<AnnotationAttributes>() {{
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("value", defaultFor(Component.class, "value"));
                    }}));
                }});
        attributesMap.put(Indexed.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedList<AnnotationAttributes>() {{
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                    }}));
                }});
        attributesMap.put(EnableTransactionManagement.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedList<AnnotationAttributes>() {{
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("order", defaultFor(EnableTransactionManagement.class, "order"));
                        put("mode", defaultFor(EnableTransactionManagement.class, "mode"));
                        put("proxyTargetClass", defaultFor(EnableTransactionManagement.class, "proxyTargetClass"));
                    }}));
                }});
        attributesMap.put(Import.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedList<AnnotationAttributes>() {{
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("value", new Class<?>[]{TransactionManagementConfigurationSelector.class});
                    }}));
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("value", new Class<?>[]{Class.forName("org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoriesRegistrar")});
                    }}));
                }});

        attributesMap.put(EnableJpaRepositories.class.getCanonicalName(),
                new LinkedList<AnnotationAttributes>() {{
                    add(new AnnotationAttributes(new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("repositoryBaseClass", data.get("repositoryBaseClass"));
                        put("basePackages", data.get("basePackages"));
                        put("value", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "value"));
                        put("excludeFilters", new AnnotationAttributes[]{});
                        put("includeFilters", new AnnotationAttributes[]{});
                        put("basePackageClasses", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "basePackageClasses"));
                        put("bootstrapMode", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "bootstrapMode"));
                        put("transactionManagerRef", data.get("transactionManagerRef"));
                        put("considerNestedRepositories", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "considerNestedRepositories"));
                        put("namedQueriesLocation", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "namedQueriesLocation"));
                        put("queryLookupStrategy", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "queryLookupStrategy"));
                        put("entityManagerFactoryRef", data.get("entityManagerFactoryRef"));
                        put("enableDefaultTransactions", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "enableDefaultTransactions"));
                        put("repositoryImplementationPostfix", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "repositoryImplementationPostfix"));
                        put("repositoryFactoryBeanClass", defaultFor(EnableJpaRepositories.class, "repositoryFactoryBeanClass"));

                    }}));
                }});


        //##################
    }

    public EnableJpaRepositoriesData(@Nullable ClassLoader classLoader, Map<String, ?> data) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
        super(classLoader);
        this.data = data;
        this.initIt();
    }

    private Object defaultFor(Class<?> clazz, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        return method.getDefaultValue();
    }
}
```

> **Sample usage of the Class to actually invoke enableJpaRepositories**
>   **programmatically:**

```
AnnotationMetadata enableJpaRepositoriesData = null;
try {
    enableJpaRepositoriesData = new EnableJpaRepositoriesData(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("repositoryBaseClass", MyJPAConnectorImpl.class);
        put("basePackages", new String[] {

                //This is where you set the repositories base packages to scan.
                //... Having your best programmatic convenience
                "org.patladj.connector.multijpa.common",
                "org.patladj.connector.multijpa.anotherrepositoriespackage",
                "org.patladj.connector.multijpa.morepackagestoscanforrepositories..."
        });

        //Ofcourse you need to create by yourself the custom transactionManagerFactory,
        // ... entityManagerFactory, JPAVendorAdapter and Datasource beans for your
        // ... custom persistence contexts using unique bean names (different than
        // ... the default Spring data names: 'entityManagerFactory', etc...)
        // ... Then "send" these bean names as references to each and every ...
        // and as many as you want persistence contexts programmatically here
        put("transactionManagerRef", myCustomPersistanceContextName + "_transactionManager");
        put("entityManagerFactoryRef", myCustomPersistanceContextName + "_entityManagerFactory");
    }});
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
}

AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource configurationSource = new AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource(
        enableJpaRepositoriesData, EnableJpaRepositories.class, applicationContext, environment, registry
);

RepositoryConfigurationExtension extension = new JpaRepositoryConfigExtension();

RepositoryConfigurationUtils.exposeRegistration(extension, registry, configurationSource);

RepositoryConfigurationDelegate delegate = new RepositoryConfigurationDelegate(configurationSource, applicationContext, environment);
delegate.registerRepositoriesIn(registry, extension);
```

> **And finally, in case if you don't know, you can use the following @Configuration class**

```
public class MultiJPABeanDefinitionRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware
```

... to override 2 of its methods to have the post process bean `registry` and `applicationContext` at your disposal to register bean definitions dynamically.
Methods to override:

```
 - public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException
 - public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException
```

Answer (score 1):

I referred this post only and created a module aware multi database aware spring data library for mysql(compatible with spring boot) in github.Some application properties need to be added and you are done .

Documentation and other details could be found at :-

https://github.com/yatharthamishra0419/spring-boot-data-multimodule-mysql

Answer (score 0):

From the `code-in-the-middle` perspective, there is a way to inject the needed functionality into an exact code-location in order to achieve the `dynamic basePackages value` feature and by `dynamic` here I mean at `runtime`.

Managed to bypass the existing spring limitation with the following logic (code is simplified in order to highlight the `code-in-the-middle` solution itself).

1. Application JPA configuration class

```
package com.me0x.meta.persistence.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.me0x.meta.spring.data.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JpaConfiguration {
    // other configuration details, if any
}
```

2. Custom version of the `EnableJpaRepositories` annotation

```
package com.me0x.meta.spring.data;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.BootstrapMode;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.DefaultRepositoryBaseClass;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy;

/**
 * This annotation is just a copy of the
 * {@link org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories}
 * spring specific one.
 * <p>
 * The dynamic loading aspect of JPA repositories is enabled IF AND ONLY IF the
 * {@link #basePackages()} property is set to the
 * {@link DynamicJpaRepositoriesRegistrar#DYNAMIC_JPA_REPOSITORIES_REGISTRATION_FEATURE_KEY}
 * value, as it is by default, otherwise this annotation works similar to the
 * spring specific one.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Remove this custom annotation and everything around it once spring
 *  starts to allow by default a dynamic loading strategy of the
 *  {@link #basePackages()} value!
 * TODO: Keep it updated (synced) to the spring specific version of it everytime
 *  the spring framework is upgraded!
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import(DynamicJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.class)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public @interface EnableJpaRepositories {

    String[] value() default {};

    String[] basePackages() default {DynamicJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.DYNAMIC_JPA_REPOSITORIES_REGISTRATION_FEATURE_KEY};

    Class<?>[] basePackageClasses() default {};

    ComponentScan.Filter[] includeFilters() default {};

    ComponentScan.Filter[] excludeFilters() default {};

    String repositoryImplementationPostfix() default "Impl";

    String namedQueriesLocation() default "";

    QueryLookupStrategy.Key queryLookupStrategy() default QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND;

    Class<?> repositoryFactoryBeanClass() default JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class;

    Class<?> repositoryBaseClass() default DefaultRepositoryBaseClass.class;

    // JPA specific configuration

    String entityManagerFactoryRef() default "entityManagerFactory";

    String transactionManagerRef() default "transactionManager";

    boolean considerNestedRepositories() default false;

    boolean enableDefaultTransactions() default true;

    BootstrapMode bootstrapMode() default BootstrapMode.DEFAULT;

    char escapeCharacter() default '\\';

}
```

3. Custom version of the `org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport` class

```
package com.me0x.meta.spring.data;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport;
import org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtension;

import com.me0x.meta.exception.ServiceException;

/**
 * @see org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoriesRegistrar
 */
@Log4j2
public class DynamicJpaRepositoriesRegistrar extends RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport {

    public static final String DYNAMIC_JPA_REPOSITORIES_REGISTRATION_FEATURE_KEY = "Dynamic";

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(final AnnotationMetadata metadata, final BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, final BeanNameGenerator generator) {
        final AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadataProxy = (AnnotationMetadata) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[]{AnnotationMetadata.class},
                (proxy, method, args) -> {
                    final Object methodResult = method.invoke(metadata, args);

                    if (methodResult instanceof Map) {
                        try {
                            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Map<String, Object> mapMethodResult = (Map<String, Object>) methodResult;
                            final Object basePackages = mapMethodResult.get("basePackages");

                            if (null != basePackages) {
                                final String[] basePackagesArray = (String[]) basePackages;

                                if (1 == basePackagesArray.length && DYNAMIC_JPA_REPOSITORIES_REGISTRATION_FEATURE_KEY.equals(basePackagesArray[0])) {
                                    mapMethodResult.put("basePackages", new String[]{"com.me0x"}); // TODO: Add dynamic values identified at runtime instead!
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            throw new ServiceException("Unable to customize the JPA repositories registration process!", e);
                        }
                    }

                    return methodResult;
                }
        );

        super.registerBeanDefinitions(annotationMetadataProxy, registry, generator);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotation() {
        return EnableJpaRepositories.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryConfigurationExtension getExtension() {
        return new JpaRepositoryConfigExtension();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

What your looking for is `@EntityScan` but it's only available in Spring Boot. The configuration you can annotate in Spring Data JPA is documented here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.java-config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
class ApplicationConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {

    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.acme.domain");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
  }
}
```