# How to inject multiple basePackages from a YAML file in @EnableJpaRepositories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to allow users of one of my libraries to specify the location of their JPA entities and Spring Data JPA repositories, something like:

```
database1:
  datasource:
    repository-package: com.sample.database1.repositories1,com.sample.database1.repositories2
    entity-packages: com.sample.database1.entities1,com.sample.database1.entities2
```

My library defines:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "${database1.datasource.repository-package}",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "database1EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "database1TransactionManager")
static class Database1DataSourceAutoConfiguration {

    @Value("${database1.datasource.entity-packages}")
    private String[] entityPackages;
```

`entityPackages` is correctly injected, containing an array with the two entity packages.

However, `basePackages = "${database1.datasource.repository-package}"` obviously doesn't work since it is referencing a String `"com.sample.database1.repositories1,com.sample.database1.repositories2"` instead of an array with two Strings.

Is there a way I can inject a `String[]` from a YML file into that annotation property? If not, is there any workaround?

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { ??? }`

Comment: [You can try this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages/51629110#51629110) I use this implement multi data source.

Answer (score 1):

Since `@EnableJpaRepositories` doesn't resolve expression language, you won't be able to provide a list of packages as one single environment property.

One alternative is to use wildcards in the property value that matches all the packages you need to scan:

```
database1.datasource.entity-packages=com.sample.database1.repositories*
```

Spring will resolve that to a "/"-based resource path, and scan:

```
classpath*:com/sample/database1/repositories*/*.class
```

Comment: You cannot use property placeholders inside @EnableJpaRepositories annotation attributes **to get a few packages instead one string with property placeholder**, but you can craft your own '@EnableJpaRepositoriesWithProperties` annotation where it will work, see the following answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages/51629110#51629110

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your own `EnableJpaRepository` annotation.I had used that implemented multi data source and can set any "basePackages" as I want.

[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages/51629110#51629110)

Comment: This approach works. I believe it should be the accepted answers. Other answers just state that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround :

1) value the `repository-package` property with `com.sample.database1` as it is a common package of these two sub-packages : `com.sample.database1.repositories1,com.sample.database1.repositories2`.

That is :

```
database1:
   datasource:
      repository-package: com.sample.database1
```

2) Other way if the base package is not always the same.
The `basePackages` attribute accepts an array. So use it to provide two distinct elements : that is a specific property by package.

For example :

```
database1:
   datasource:
      repository-package-1: com.sample.database1.repositories1
      repository-package-2: com.sample.database1.repositories2
```

And use it :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 
            {"${database1.datasource.repository-package-1}", 
             "${database1.datasource.repository-package-2}"}, 
            ...
)
static class Database1DataSourceAutoConfiguration {
```

Comment: The problem is that I would like to generalize the content of `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages =`. So there could be 1, 2, n packages to include there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think the syntax of your YAML isn't the correct syntax to specify arrays. 
Shouldn't an array in YAML look like this?

```
database1:
  datasource:
    entity-packages: 
      - com.sample.database1.entities1
      - com.sample.database1.entities2
```

Or if you want to have it in a single line you could use the JSON-syntax

```
database1:
  datasource:
    entity-packages: ['com.sample.database1.entities1', 'com.sample.database1.entities1']
```

**Update**

I found a [blog post](https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2016/02/26/injecting-list-with-spring-from-yaml/) exactly about your problem. It looks like you need to use `@ConfigurationProperties` instead of `@Value`, if you want to use YAML.
I didn't had any problems using `.properties` instead of `.yml` like this:

```
database1.datasource.entity-packages=com.sample.database1.entities1, com.sample.database1.entities1
```

Comment: But how do I pass those values into that annotation property that is expecting an array?

Comment: If you use `application.properties` instead of  `application.yml`, you can just keep your java code. For a reason, that i don't understand to be honest, spring throws an `IllegalArgumentException` telling me that it could not resolve the placeholder when i use the yml-syntax (Just like described in the blog post i linked)