# Spring Data JPA : externalize to a property file the @EnableJpaRepositories basePackages configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I wanted to externalize the configuration for @EnableJPARepositories basePackages.

I have two different sample packages below

- com.project.ph.dao
- sample.project.jpa.repositories

I tried property externalization below (not working for multiple packages)

ProjectConfig.class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"${basePackages}"})
```

config.properties

```
basePackages=com.project.ph.dao,sample.project.jpa.repositories
```

Is there any other way to externalize this configuration for multiple packages?

Thanks!

Comment: No there isn't. attributes of an annotation have static values and do you really want to control that from the outside, it basically means you have lost control over what is bootstrapped in your application.

Comment: You cannot use property placeholders inside @EnableJpaRepositories annotation attributes **to get a few packages instead one string with property placeholder**, but you can craft your own '@EnableJpaRepositoriesWithProperties` annotation where it will work, see the following answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages/51629110#51629110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use SPEL inside the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. Reason being that the annotation might exist on a configuration bean with additional property sources defined that could override the properties used in the annotation, so you'd have a chicken and egg scenario trying to load the beans. But you can still solve your problem using Spring's configuration mechanisms.

### With Spring Boot

Instead of declaring all of the packages in a single class, create two or more `@Configuration` beans that are enabled based on properties using the [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation from Spring Boot, e.g.:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.project.ph.dao")
@ConditionalOnProperty("com.project.ph.dao.enabled")
public class PhProjectRepostoriesConfiguration {
}
```

And then another:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "sample.project.jpa.repositories")
@ConditionalOnProperty("sample.project.jpa.repositories.enabled")
public class SampleProjectRepostoriesConfiguration {
}
```

Then in your `application.properties` file:

```
sample.project.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
com.project.ph.dao.enabled=false
```

### Without Spring Boot

This is similar, except instead of using `@ConditionalOnProperty`, you'll just use [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html). This requires you to implement a [`Condition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) class that will check the properties instead.

### Additional Notes

When using the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, the default `basePackages` [will be the package of the annotated class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.java-config), so you could also drop these `@Configuration` beans into the `com.project.ph.dao` and `sample.project.jpa.repositories` packages and remove the `basePackages` declaration from the annotation. You'll still need the rest of the annotations, but it's one less hard-coded value to manage.

### References

- [`@ConditionalOnProperty` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) (docs.spring.io)
- [`@Conditional` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) (docs.spring.io)
- [`Condition` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) (docs.spring.io)
- [Spring Auto-Configuration Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) (docs.spring.io)
- [`@EnableJpaRepositories` usage documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.java-config) (docs.spring.io)
- [Additional information when working with multiple `DataSource` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663025/spring-data-jpa-multiple-enablejparepositories) (stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You cannot use property placeholders inside @EnableJpaRepositories annotation attributes **to get a few packages instead one string with property placeholder**, but you can craft your own '@EnableJpaRepositoriesWithProperties` annotation where it will work, see the following answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages/51629110#51629110