# assign entity to persistence-unit (spring-boot, spring-data-jpa)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to support two database connections. Due to legacy reasons, it must be possible to configure in a external file, which database contains which table.

Using JEE I'd have a persistence unit like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="unit-one">
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Vpt</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Azg</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Aus</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Txt</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Aco</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Aks</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Apr</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Aie</class>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="unit-two">
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Vif</class>
        <class>com.example.io.jpa.Vid</class>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The entities my be rearranged between the persistence-units as needed.

I know the datasource parameters and I'm having a list of Entites that must be assigned to unit-two. Everything else goes to unit-one.

Up to now I did not find a way in spring boot, to assign a Entity.class to a 
**LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean**, everything I found was based on packages.
If there is no other way I'll put all the entities in a separate package, but usually there is a less ugly solution I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

I found someone with a similar problem. The solution he described works for me too.
It's still ugly, because I had to copy/duplicate several classes from spring.
So the way chosen was not intended to be.

The way to assign Entities at runtime is:

```
 @Bean(name = "someEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean someEntityManagerFactory(
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
      return builder
              .dataSource(tradingDataSource())
              .packages("com.example.db.model.pkgtable1",
                  "com.example.db.model.pkgtable2",
                  "com.example.db.model.pkgtable3"
                  )
              .build();
  }
```

The each entity in it's own package hack, is still needed.

But in truth this is only the half way. We have the same problem with the repositories.
How to solve this, can be found here:

[Spring Data JPA - How to programmatically set JpaRepository base packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635650/spring-data-jpa-how-to-programmatically-set-jparepository-base-packages)